# fail to install rgbdslam on electric

Tags: slam, turtlebot, rgbd, ros-electric, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have used rgbdslam[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) on furete . recently,i install rgbdslam[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam_electric) on turtlebot.but failed. when i type :rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam          the error message is :the svn: OPTIONS the failure https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk: server certificate validation failure certificate issuer is not trusted (https://svn.openslam.org).  any suggestion is appreciation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63115/fail-to-install-rgbdslam-on-electric/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok, i have solve this problem via [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/50745/rgbdslam-error-trust-certificate-g2o-problem/)

---

Originally posted by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) with karma: 78 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0